# Lazy load Project Wonderful ads in responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement lazy loading for the Project Wonderful ads on my website. Since the site is responsive, I only want to load the ads when they would be displayed to the user.

The async code supplied by Project Wonderful to load the ads is in the `<head>` section of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){function pw_load(){
      if(arguments.callee.z)return;else arguments.callee.z=true;
      var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script');
      var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;
      s.src='//www.projectwonderful.com/pwa.js';
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}
   if (window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent('DOMContentLoaded',pw_load);
    window.attachEvent('onload',pw_load);}
   else{
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',pw_load,false);
    window.addEventListener('load',pw_load,false);}})();
</script>
```

In another file, `ad-switcher.js`, I am using Modernizr media queries to dynamically set the content of the div with the ad:

```
var sidebarAdLoaded; // So that ad is only loaded when crossing the width threshhold

var adSwitcher = function(){
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 1024px)')) {
        if (!sidebarAdLoaded) {
            jQuery('#sidebar-ad').html("\
                <!-- Project Wonderful Ad Box Code -->\
                <div id='pw_adbox_80019_3_0'></div>\
                <script type='text/javascript'></script>\
            ");

            // I think I need to re-fetch the ad here

            sidebarAdLoaded = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#sidebar-ad').empty();
        sidebarAdLoaded = false;
    }
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    sidebarAdLoaded = false;
    adSwitcher(); // Set the div content once on page load...
    $(window).resize(adSwitcher); // ...and then whenever it is resized
});
```

**Problem:**

1. Load page at >1024 px, the ad loads and displays properly
2. Shrink width to <1024 px, the ad disappears
3. Expand width to >1024 px, the ad does not display

I verified that the content of the div is being set properly, just the ad is not displaying. I think I need to call `pw_load()` in the spot I commented, but I can't figure out how.

**What I Tried:**

I tried calling `pw_load();`, but I get function not undefined. (Possibly because it is declared in that weird way?)

Since pw_load is being attached to the `DOMContentLoaded` and `onload` events, I thought I might need to reload the div (I could reload the whole page, but that defeats the whole purpose of lazy loading). I tried adding `jQuery('#sidebar-ad').load();` but that also didn't work.

`ad-switcher.js` was being loaded in the `<head>` section before the Project Wonderful async code, so I moved it to the end of the `<body>` section, but the problem still occurred.